# Как правильно выровнить треугольник?

Tags: css

Есть два блока.

Верхний и нижний( `footer`)

В Нижнем блоке есть треуголник с белым задним фоном.

Вопрос как его выровнить равномерно верхнего блока.То есть он всегда должен быть в одной ширине с верхним блоком

Как он сейчас работает можете увидеть запустив мой код и увеличив размер просмотра то есть смотрите на весь экран так как в маленькой ширине не поймете сути проблемы.

Как он должен быть вот картинка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка немнога мутная но вы поймете

```css
.oldcity-question-five {
  background: url("https://preview.ibb.co/ni0ev8/sb5l.jpg") left top no-repeat, url("https://preview.ibb.co/mbssF8/sb5r.jpg") right top no-repeat;
  background-color: #d08b48;
  background-size: contain;
}
.oldcity-question-five .first-question {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 90px 0;
  color: #fff;
}
.oldcity-question-five .first-question .question {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.oldcity-question-five .first-question .question-variants .question-variant {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

footer {
  background: url("https://image.ibb.co/i1kzdT/endleft.png") left top no-repeat, url("https://preview.ibb.co/ioUsyT/endright.png") right top no-repeat;
  background-color: #721716;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100%;
}
footer .center {
  position: relative;
}
footer .center #triangle-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 410px solid transparent;
  border-top: 120px solid #fff;
}
footer .center #triangle-down h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
}
footer .center .youre-result {
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}
footer .center button {
  border: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
  color: #063e5f;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
footer .center button:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 0 #0a4d68;
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 0 #0a4d68;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 0 #0a4d68;
}
footer .center button a {
  color: #063e5f;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="oldcity-question-five">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="first-question">
        <h6 class="question">НА КАКОЙ СТАНЦИИ МЕТРО ЗВУЧИТ ОТРЫВОК МЕЛОДИИ, ОДНОИМЕННЫЙ С ПРОИЗВЕДЕНИЕМ БУльдозера?</h6>
        <ul class="question-variants">
          <li class="question-variant">Самосвал</li>
          <li class="question-variant">Криштиано рональдно </li>
          <li class="question-variant">Пикассо</li>
          <li class="question-variant">Том круз</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-4">

      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4">
        <div class="center">
          <div class="final-result" id="triangle-down">
            <h1>13 / 15</h1>
          </div>
          <p class="youre-result">Вы хорошо ориентируетесь в Дубаи,
            но не уделяете внимание истории и деталям. 
            Чтобы восполнить некоторые пробелы, 
            предлагаем сходить на тур 
            по любимому городу с гидом из</p>

          <button class="share-result"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Share result</a></button>
          <div class="footer-logo">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="navbar-left"><img src="assets/images/LogoBSfull.png"></a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```